# "It is not good for man to be alone" : Is this some sort of commandment, and does it apply to b'nei Noach?

Tags: gentiles, marriage, noachide-laws, noahidism, genesis-bereishith

> וַיֹּ֨אמֶר֙ יְהֹוָ֣ה אֱלֹהִ֔ים לֹא־ט֛וֹב הֱי֥וֹת הָֽאָדָ֖ם לְבַדּ֑וֹ
> אֶֽעֱשֶׂה־לּ֥וֹ עֵ֖זֶר כְּנֶגְדּֽוֹ: ‏
>
> And the Lord God said, "It is not good that man is alone; I shall make
> him a helpmate opposite him."

[Bereishit 2:18](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8166#v=18)

This would seem to imply that all men who are not married, are not good, and that no man can be good until he is married. Is this true?

If my understanding is correct, all decrees unto Noach and Adam count as Noachide Commandments, and I am wondering if this ethos extends to that, and what are the implications?

Can you even call this idea a commandment, seeing as it reads more as an observation?

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't imply unmarried men aren't good, but that it is not good for there to be unmarried men.

Comment: @DoubleAA Is the act, to willfully aid and perpetuate a non-good state of affairs, not good? And if so, are not men defined by their actions?

Comment: Who said anything about willful acts?

Comment: @DoubleAA I did. Willfull in the Mens Rea context, which extends that to being reckless.

Comment: You didn't say that though. If you have unstated assumptions in your question, it will be hard to understand it.

Comment: Sounds like an observation to me...

Comment: Is this enumerated in the lists presented by those experts who have counted the various commandments? Is this language precedented elsewhere as a way of constructing a commandment? Is there any citable opinion that refers to it as a commondment? If not, why assume it IS a commandment?